# How to preserve Identity Specification in SQL Server on Import/Export?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, data-migration, data-import, data-export

I exported a SQL database from one server to another.  Both are running SQL Server Express.   However, I noticed that some settings were not preserved.  For example, the Identity Specification is set to "No" on the Destination Server, despite the specification being set to "Yes" on the Source Server.  This brings up two questions:

1. Are there any other settings that have not been preserved that I should know about?
2. How can I preserve these settings without assigning each one individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly did you export the db? I know that if you make a backup of the db on one server and restore it on another, you wont lose any settings.